# How to use tilesLoaded in angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, angular-google-maps, agm-map

How to use `tilesLoaded` in agm angular google map. I want to do some action after map has fully loaded. Is there any example to use `tilesLoaded` in angular (v8)?

https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/commit/d4f1371

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `tilesLoaded` event to your `agm-map` as follows:

```
<agm-map  
  [latitude]=51.673858
  [longitude]=7.815982
  [zoom]=8
  (tilesLoaded)="handleOnTilesLoaded()">
</agm-map>
```

Then add your own behavior within that function, e.g.:

```
handleOnTilesLoaded(){
    console.log("Tiles have loaded.");
}
```

Hope this helps you!